# How to update the tables in dataclass IBM?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am trying to update a dataclass table with extra values after inserting some fields in the columns,again if i want insert the details in the same column,its not working,it gets in the second row,could anyone please help me,i want this answer as soon as possible

Comment: Hi Parvathi,  It would be helpful if you explain the approach that you are using, steps and what the error is that you get when you try.  Are you doing this in MobileFirst Data and are you using JSON?

Comment: I am able to update the table using the position,but now my problem is that i m not able to retrieve all the value from the bluemix table,

Comment: So it sounds like you solved your original problem and now have a new problem.  You really should make your question clearer. Post your own solution as the answer.  You should also post a new question for your new problem. Otherwise your question once answered won't be of help to anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    // Find a set of objects by class
    IBMQuery<Item> queryByClass = IBMQuery.queryForClass(Item.class);

    // Find a specific object
    IBMQuery<Item> queryForObject = myItem.getQuery();

    query.find().continueWith(new Continuation<List<Item>, Void>() {

        @Override
        public Void then(Task<List<Item>> task) throws Exception {
            if (task.isFaulted()) {
                // Handle errors
            } else {
                // do more work
                List<Item> objects = task.getResult();
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
```

This code came from http://mbaas-gettingstarted.ng.bluemix.net/android

Answer (score 1):

This is how I updated the row in bluemix by getting a particular column value position. Here is the code.

This is the code for getting the entire values from the bluemix table:

```
IBMQuery<Company> query = IBMQuery.queryForClass(Company.CLASS_NAME);
        query.find().continueWith(new Continuation<List<Company>, Void>() {

            public Void then(Task<List<Company>> task) throws Exception {
                final List<Company> objects = task.getResult();
                // Log if the find was cancelled.
                if (task.isCancelled()) {
                    Log.e(CLASS_NAME, "Exception : Task " + task.toString()
                            + " was cancelled.");
                }
                // Log error message, if the find task fails.
                else if (task.isFaulted()) {
                    Log.e(CLASS_NAME, "Exception : "
                            + task.getError().getMessage());
                }

                // If the result succeeds, load the list.
                else {
                    companyList.clear();
                    for (IBMDataObject storeObject : objects) {
                        companyList.add((Company) storeObject);
                    }
                    if (task.isCompleted()) {
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(2);

                    }

                }
```

Where Company is the name of the Table and companyList is the company class array list.

After this code is executed the companylist will get all the rows and columns values stored in bluemix from which we can get the required row by using the query

```
query.whereKeyEqualsTo(User.RegisterName, userName);
query.whereKeyEqualsTo(User.Password, password);
```

Where User is the table name 
RegisterName and Password are static variable defined in the User Class
userName and password is the user defined given inputs.
By getting the position of the required row retrieved in companyList, I do the update in the following way:

```
Company companyObject=Company.getPosition(position);
companyObject.setName("Something");
companyObject.save() query......
```

Now the problem is I'm able to do the update properly, but I'm not able to retrieve the table values from bluemix using the code which I mentioned in the top.